# Converting a C++ class to a template class

Tags: c++, templates

I just finished creating my binary tree class only to realise that I was supposed to make it as a template. I've spent hours now trying to get to convert it to a template, but I keep getting a multitude of errors ranging from "invalid use of template-name" to "extra qualification of a member". I am new to the concept of templates but I have an idea of what I'm trying to achieve.

BTree.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "BTree.h"
using namespace std;

BTree::BTree(board startboard, string startplayer)
    {
    treeboard = startboard;
    player = startplayer;
    root = new BTNode(treeboard, player,-1,-1);
    }


BTree::~BTree()
    {
    delete root;
    }

int BTree::sumtree()
    {
    if (root->getvalue(-1) > root->getvalue(1))
        return root->getchildposition(-1);
    else
        return root->getchildposition(1);
    }
```

BTree.h

```c++
#include <string>
#include "BTNode.h"
#include "board.h"
using namespace std;
class BTree
{
public:
    BTree(board startboard, string startplayer);
    ~BTree();
    int sumtree();

private:
    string player;
    board treeboard;
    BTNode *root;
};
```

'startplayer' is currently a string, I would like this to be the generic template type.

What should my process be for turning this into a single template file?

Comment: Don't feel bad about implementing this non-template at first. It's called `lifting`.  It's usually easier to create a class that works on just an `int` or `string` and make it work properly, then lift out the general form. http://www.generic-programming.org/about/intro/lifting.php

Comment: Why do you copy startboard and startplayer twice in the constructor?

Comment: @NeilKirk leftover code from when I dramatically changed the class, didn't realise those lines were redundant now; thanks for the heads up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, let's first look what errors or other deficits your code has:

- Your `BTree` has a custom dtor, because it holds resources. But you are violating the rule-of-3:
  You need to define or delete, at minimum, your assignment-operator and copy-ctor.
  As an alternative (preferable), change `BTNode *root;` to use `std::unique_ptr`.
- The first thing included in the implementation-file should always be its own header, to find broken dependencies in the header.
- The header should include everything neccessary to use it, and not one bit more.

Now, there are good reasons why templates are usually header-only:

The compiler needs the definition to instantiate it.
Use the opportunity to move some of the functions into the class.

Next, you define a template like this:

```
template<class T> class BTree {
    int BTree::sumtree();
};
```

And non-inline members like this:

```
template<class T> int BTree<T>::sumtree() {
    return //...
}
```

In the template, you can use the type-argument like a normal type.

A note on `BTNode`: It's an implementation-detail of `BTree`, so put its definition into the class (which makes templating it the same and using it easier as well.)
Alternatively, if you don't actually need all the template-arguments for `BTNode` as well (or want to share its implementation), template it separately.
Don't forget to change all references from `BTree` though.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on 'std::unique_ptr', I do not understand how I am using this pointer wrong.

Comment: @Matt: I'm not saying you are using the pointer wrong, I'm saying the implicitly defined copy-constructor and assignment-operator are wrong for you. [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) is a smart-pointer, which would simplify handling memory-allocation and deallocation. (Allowing you to remove the dtor and follow the rule-of-zero instead.)

Answer (score 0):

First of all to use templates in C++ all of your executable code NEEDS to be in the .h file so it is available at compile time.

Then to template your class, the usual way is to make it like :

```
template<class T>
class BTree
{
  Btree(T startPlayer)
  {
       player = startPlayer;
  }
  // ... snip ...
  T player;
}
```

Comment: Have I implemented this correctly? http://pastebin.com/7sP7cndb
I am getting this error on compilation http://pastebin.com/HpjCcCay

Comment: @Matt: You still have all errors and deficits I listed.

Comment: "g++  main.o board.o board.h BTNode.o BTNode.h BTree.h -o test"
You should NEVER compile .h files

Comment: Okay, noted. How do I compile the template; I thought it was supposed to be inside the header?

Comment: It is. In the files that will use BTree, just #include "BTree.h" and the code will get generated properly.

Comment: #include "simply" copy pastes the content of the file you include to the file calling it.

Comment: @Matt: Consider using [ideone](http://ideone.com/ScZg4I) or [coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b7e4bc35e45015d3) to show compiling/running code.

Comment: Okay! The error was because I was including my board class before BTree from the main class. It works great now, thanks everybody.